# How can i able to show 2 columns in a dropdown?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have this code below and need to revise to show 2 columns in my dropdown list.

```
<?php
  require_once('includes/init.php');
  $all_sites = find_all('site_info');
?>
<?php

<?php
 if(isset($_POST['add_site'])){
   $req_fields = array('siteid');
   validate_fields($req_fields);
   if(empty($errors)){
     $p_siteid   = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['siteid']));
     $query  = "INSERT INTO site_table (siteid)";
     $query .=" VALUES ("'{$p_siteid}')";

     if($db->query($query)){
       $session->msg('s',"Site Added ");
       redirect('site.php', false);
     } else {
       $session->msg('d',' Sorry failed to add!');
       redirect('site.php', false);
     }
   } else{
     $session->msg("d", $errors);
     redirect('site.php',false);
   }
 }
?>
```

My form div is like this below but only for one column in my dropdown.

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-12">
  <form method="post" action="add_site.php">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <select class="form-control" name="siteid">
           <option value="">Select Site</option>
             <?php foreach ($all_sites as $site): ?>
              <option value="<?php echo (int)$site['id'] ?>">
             <?php echo $site['site_name']; ?></option>
             <?php endforeach; ?>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group clearfix">
        <button type="submit" name="add_site" class="btn btn-primary">Add Site</button>
      </div>
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

I wanted to add another column beside each other. How can show 2 columns in my dropdown list so i could see the value of the other column.

Thanks.

```
| Site | Status      |
| 2000 | Active      |
| 2001 | In Progress |
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand the concept,

```
<option value=" option value "> option text </option>
```

every `option` tag contains `option value` & `option text`, so in case you want to show multiple values than you have to merge these multiple values and show them as merged string in `option text` like:

```
<?php foreach ($all_sites as $site): ?>
<option value="<?php echo (int)$site['id'] ?>">
    <?php echo $site['site_name'].' - '.$site['something_else']; ?>
</option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: yes. thanks. How can i add a table like for this dropdown? to make it more nice including the column name

Comment: Didn't get you?

Comment: What i meant was.. the above code will only show, like "2000 - Active" , etc. (without a table).  I wanted to have it in table with column name for each field.

Comment: Add a more column in your table and insert the values in it fetch and show them